# File to import not found or unreadable: compass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I successfully installed Sass, but I'm having trouble importing Compass.

The following is the error detail:

```
*Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
              Load path: H:/HTML/___keoFull/sass
.....
Backtrace:
mainKeo.scss:2
style.scss:2
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:217:in `visit_import'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:227:in `block in visit_import'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:227:in `map'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:227:in `visit_import'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:109:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:121:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:108:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:128:in `visit_root'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:100:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:341:in `update_stylesheet'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:203:in `block in update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:201:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:201:in `update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:235:in `watch'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/plugin.rb:107:in `method_missing'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/exec.rb:444:in `watch_or_update'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/exec.rb:307:in `process_result'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/exec.rb:41:in `parse'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/lib/sass/exec.rb:21:in `parse!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.6/bin/sass:9:in `<top (required)>'*
```

Comment: Why did you unaccept my explicit answer in favor of a short answer that adds nothing new?

Comment: I think I just accepted whatever works for me on my first try lol. Your answer was great, for the sake of everyone else who visit this question I will accept urs. GJ

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Compass adjusts the way partials are imported. It allows importing components based solely on their name, without specifying the path.

Before you can do `@import 'compass';`, you should:

Install Compass as a Ruby gem:

```
gem install compass
```

After that, you should use Compass's own command line tool to compile your SASS code:

```
cd path/to/your/project/
compass compile
```

Note that Compass reqiures a configuration file called `config.rb`. You should create it for Compass to work.

The minimal `config.rb` can be as simple as this:

```
css_dir =   "css"
sass_dir =  "sass"
```

And your SASS code should reside in `sass/`.

Instead of creating a configuration file manually, you can create an empty Compass project with `compass create <project-name>` and then copy your SASS code inside it.

Note that if you want to use Compass extensions, you will have to:

1. require them from the `config.rb`;
2. import them from your SASS file.

More info here: http://compass-style.org/help/

Comment: +1 Great answer; my issue was that I wasn't requiring them in `config.rb`

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice.  This question and answer are NOT for rails.

Comment: thank you so much, this was the finishing touch for me in installing compass/sass with laravel

Comment: Agreed, this answer helped more than the accepted one.  `config.rb` was the key.

Comment: Where does/should the `config.rb` file reside?

Comment: @therobyouknow, normally, in the root of your project. But you can place it wherever you want: just run the `compass` command line tool from there and provide paths relative to that folder.

Comment: Hm, got my config.rb setup correctly.. compass config runs fine, but I am still getting this "file to import not found or unreadable" error.. Its looking for a file called compass.. Compass is working, but is it suppose to be finding a file named compass?

Answer (score 16):

I'm seeing this issue using Rails 4.0.2 and [compass-rails 1.1.3](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails)

I got past this error by moving `gem 'compass-rails'` outside of the `:assets` group in my `Gemfile`

It looks something like this:

```
# stuff
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 1.1.3'
group :assets do
  # more stuff
end
```

Comment: I experienced the same. It turned out to be because the assets group is deprecated as of Rails 4.

Comment: I had it like this, but had to restart the server ^^)

Answer (score 3):

I was uninstalled compass 1.0.1 and install compass 0.12.7, this fix problem for me

```
$ sudo gem uninstall compass
$ sudo gem install compass -v 0.12.7
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're like me and came here looking for a way to make sass --watch work with compass, the answer is to use Compass' version of watch, simply:

```
compass watch
```

If you're on a Mac and don't yet have the gem installed, you might run into errors when you try to install the Compass gem, due to permission problems that arise on OSX versions later than 10.11. Install ruby with Homebrew to get around this. See [this answer for how to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015875/operation-not-permitted-usr-bin-update-rubygems)

Alternatively you could just use CodeKit, but if you're stubborn like me and want to use Sublime Text and command line, this is the route to go.

Answer (score 2):

In short, if you've installed the gem the run:

```
compass compile
```

in your rails root dir

Comment: Do you need to do this every time you begin to work on the project?

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero You compile every time you make changes to the SCSS files