# File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3 on compiling a ready made .SCSS file

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I just recently downloaded a ready made project and it has scss files on it too. when I tried to compile main.scss file using [koala-app](http://koala-app.com/) it gives me this error.

> C:\Users\1\Desktop\agency\sass\main.scss Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.
>
> ```
>           Load paths:
>             C:/Program Files (x86)/Koala (DEPRECATED)
>             C:/Users/1/Desktop/agency/sass
>     on line 2 of C:\Users\1\Desktop\agency\sass\partials\_base.scss
>     from line 4 of C:\Users\1\Desktop\agency\sass\main.scss   Use --trace for backtrace.
> ```

by the way line 4 : @import "compass/css3";

I already installed:

```
ruby 1.9.3p545
gem 1.8.28
```

main.scss

```
// MAIN

// all modules, general styles and variables
@import "partials/base";
@import "partials/general";

// third-party
@import "vendors/supersized";
@import "vendors/font-awesome.min";
@import "vendors/brankic-icon";
@import "vendors/flexslider";
@import "vendors/animate";
@import "vendors/jpreloader";
@import "vendors/magnific-popup";

// web elements/components
@import "partials/hero-unit";
@import "partials/about";
@import "partials/services";
@import "partials/works";
@import "partials/call-to-action";
@import "partials/team";
@import "partials/testimonial";
@import "partials/contact";
@import "partials/twitter-stream";
@import "partials/footer";
```

_base.scss

```
/* ------------------ BASE STYLES ------------------ */
// import compass
@import "compass/css3";
// all variables
```

any suggestions would really be appreciated.. thanks ( note: newbie on sass :)

Comment: If you compile this with Compass, not using Koala, does it still give an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what I did was create a new sass project using ruby's command prompt "compass create newproject" then transfer the files there. then it worked.. I really did not solve the problem, thought but somehow I found a way to make it work. heres the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511874/file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-compass) for reference.