# Compass with grunt "File to import not found or unreadable"

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass

I am having issues importing compass, it's definitely installed (gem list confirms that), breakpoint and susy work fine but it doesn't like the compass import...

Error:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
   Load paths:
     /Users/xx/dev/roomfully/listaroom-app
     /Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/susy-2.2.2/sass
     /Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/breakpoint-2.5.0/stylesheets
    on line 1 of public/sass/app.scss
Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    require: [
                        'susy', 
                        'breakpoint', 
                        'compass', 
                        'compass-normalize'
                    ]
                },
                files: {
                    'public/app.css': 'public/sass/app.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            dist: {
                files: 'public/sass/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
}
```

app.scss

```
@import 'compass';
@import 'compass-normalize';
@import 'breakpoint';
@import 'susy';

body {
    display: none
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an answer about this question, [File to import not found or unreadable: compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511874/file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-compass), but before you check this link, maybe you can try to set sass option "compass: true", like this:

```
sass: {
  options: {
    compass: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem as below :-
There was a problem of path resolution by compass as all the paths mentioned are relative paths of the dependencies. Try to make the total path length smaller.
I had too much hierarchical folder structure as a result when the total path was resolved, it was greater than the allowed length.
try putting your folder(containing the whole project structure) directly in C drive.

Answer (score 1):

To add on top of your answer @pramod, The error that blocks compass build is "File to import not found or unreadable: compass" is because NTFS limitation of 256 characters on path strings.

This also happened to me importing theme sass files about my app sources that must respect my project hierarchy.

I think that compass resolve the absolute path concatenating relative ones, wasting a lot of chars ("C:\a\b\c....\b\c\d" instead of "C:\a\b\c\d").