# File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: css, sass, compass

I get this error below in terminal, and I do not know what the problem is...

```
  "error ./sass/screen.scss (Line 8: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset.
  error ./style.scss (Line 2: File to import not found or unreadable: reset.scss."
```

Here is the information about those lines that has an error.

screen.scss Line 8 : @import "compass/reset";

style.scss Line 2: @import "reset.scss";

I appreciate it if somebody could help me out with this.  Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked file permissions?

Comment: Yes, seems like that is not a problem here...

Comment: Tried this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511874/file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-compass)?